# Does a non-exchangeable empirical reverse-martingale exist?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions

Consider a possible finite sequence $\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots$ of random variables and consider the measure-valued empirical process
$$\eta_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{\xi_i}}{n},\:\:\: n=1,2,\dots$$
Assume $\eta_n$ is a reverse martingale, in the sense that $(\int fd\eta_n)$ is a reverse-martingale for every $f\geq 0$. Does it automatically hold that $(\eta_n)$ is exchangeable? I.e., does it hold that for any $f_1,\dots,f_n$ and permutation $p$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$

$$E\left(\int f_1\eta_1\cdots \int f_n\eta_n\right )= E\left(\int f_1\eta_{p(1)}\cdots \int f_n\eta_{p(n)}\right)?$$

---

I've managed to prove that the last two terms commute, by an argument along

\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(\int f_1\eta_1\cdots \int f_n\eta_n\right)&=&E\left(E\left(\int f_1\eta_1\cdots \int f_n\eta_n|\mathcal{F}_{n}\right)\right)\\
&=&E\left(\int f_1\eta_1\cdots E\left(\int f_{n-1}\eta_{n-1}\int f_n\eta_n|\mathcal{F}_{n}\right)\right)\\
&=&E\left(\int f_1\eta_1\cdots \int f_{n-2}\eta_{n-2}\int f_{n-1}\eta_{n}\int f_n\eta_n\right),
\end{eqnarray*}
where the reverse-martingale property was used. Here $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(\eta_n,\eta_{n+1},\dots)$. However, this argument does not seem to extend to more indices.  I'm beginning to suspect there may be a counter-example where exchangeability does not hold.

Any input or reference is appreciated.

---

I posted this question also on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173995/does-a-non-exchangeable-empirical-reverse-martingale-exist)

Comment: What are your sigma-fields, $F_n$ ?  It seems to me that you would not expect to get a reverse martingale conditioning on a fixed  filtration, it would be a different filtration for every f, e.g., with $f=x^2$ you want $F_1 = F(X_1^2, X_1^2 + X_2^2,....), F_2 = F(X_1^2 + X_2^2, X_1^2 + X_2^2  + X_2^2 + ....) $ etc.  Here it looks like $F_i = F(X_1,...,X_i)$.

Comment: @michael Thanks for your comment. I've now edited.